# Unable to generate anything with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, static-site

When I run Jekyll it does not generate anything. The output I see:

```
Configuration from /home/mbsheikh/techtraits/techtraits-blog/_config.yml
Auto-regenerating enabled: /home/mbsheikh/techtraits/techtraits-blog -> /home/mbsheikh/techtraits/techtraits-blog/_site
[2012-06-15 23:23:03] regeneration: 118 files changed
```

The `_site` directory is empty. Is there a way to debug Jekyll? I changed a couple of files and still don't see anything in `_site`.

Comment: Have you tried moving all of the files out of the directory and progressively adding them in until you see the failure? (You don't need to do it one-by-one; in blocks of (e.g.) 10 files so that you can narrow down which files are causing the problem.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `auto=false` in the`_config.yml`, then run `jekyll` again, then you will see the ruby error trace info.