# Jekyll: blog post ignored - how to debug?

Tags: blogs, jekyll, static-site

I am trying to set up a blog on github.io using jekyll ([site](http://jmini.github.io/), [source](https://github.com/jmini/jmini.github.io))

My problem is that my article in the `_posts` folder semms to be ignored. I would like to debug the site generation.

I have seen this advice to [debug jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060556/unable-to-generate-anything-with-jekyll), but so far I did not understood what is missing.
Can I see if jekyll consider my file or if it is ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your files names replace underscore by hyphen.

**wrong** : 2014-11-01_part_of_it.md

**good** : 2014-11-01-part-of-it.md

Answer (score 0):

the article/post needs a publish date in the front matter

```
---
date: 2014-11-01 08:57:00 GMT
---
```

Comment: Sorry about this. During my first tries I had this date param in the front matter headers, but not in the format you have indicated. I have repushed it to GitHub. No luck for the moment. I will try to continue to debug it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind that your post won't be generated if the publishing date (including the daylight saving time, in my case) is in the future.

```
date:   2018-07-18 18:00:00 +0100

       Reading: _posts/2018-07-18-no-more-ssh-login.markdown
      Skipping: _posts/2018-07-18-no-more-ssh-login.markdown has a future date
```

Had to run `bundle exec jekyll serve --verbose` to realize it.